# ListBox with ComboBox DataTemplate Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I currently have a `Combobox` in a `Datatemplate` for a `Listbox`. I've bound the `Combobox` to a `string[]`. This is working fine.

What I would like is when a `Combobox` is changed, the index of the `Listbox` should be associated with the string in the array.
I.e. if I select the 4th item in the `Combobox` in the 3rd line of the `Listbox` my data should be represented by < string (`Combobox` string), int (`Listbox` index)> but to save on duplicated data I would like to use this data as my `Combobox` binding.

I was thinking I could use a key value pair but I'm unsure how I would bind this to the `Combobox` that is in a `DataTemplate` (or if this is the best way of doing this).

**Note**

Obviously this means that each `Combobox` string can only be associated with one `Listbox` index at a time.
Therefore, I would like if each `Combobox` string could only be set once in the `Listbox`, i.e. if I select `Combobox` index 3 in index 4 of the `Listbox` then `Listbox` index 5 which already had `Combobox` 3 should be reset to blank. I will probably in the `Combobox` changed event go through and reset the other `Comboboxes` if it is for the same string.

**Sample**

OK so the following binding works;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="lbxHeaderDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding Item1}"></Label>
            <ComboBox Name="cbxTest" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding 
                 Item2}" DisplayMemberPath="Key"></ComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Width="auto" Height="auto">
    <ListBox Name="lbxFields"
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource lbxHeaderDataTemplate}" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
private List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> cbxOptions2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
cbxOptions2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("", 0));
cbxOptions2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Identifier", 0));
cbxOptions2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Family Identifier", 0));
cbxOptions2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("File Path", 0));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lbxDatFields.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>((i * 10).ToString(), cbxOptions2));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I ended up using. Please feel free to suggest a better answer.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="lbxHeaderDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{Binding Item1}"></Label>
            <ComboBox Name="cbxTest" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding 
                 Item2}" DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                SelectionChanged="cbxTest_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Width="auto" Height="auto">
    <ListBox Name="lbxFields"
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource lbxHeaderDataTemplate}" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
private Dictionary<string, int> cbxOptions2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
cbxOptions2.Add("", 0);
cbxOptions2.Add("Identifier", 0);
cbxOptions2.Add("Family Identifier", 0);
cbxOptions2.Add("File Path", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lbxDatFields.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, int>>((i * 10).ToString(), cbxOptions2));
}

private void cbxTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox test = (ComboBox)sender;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(test);
    Label currentTxt = null;
    foreach (object o in ((Grid)parent).Children)
    {
        if (o is Label)
        {
            currentTxt = (Label)o;
        }
    }
}
```